# Snakeviz only showing one function

Tags: python, cprofile

I am trying to use Snakeviz to profile my python code. I use

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # main()
    cProfile.run('main()', "stats.prof")
```

to start the profiling. The issue I am having is that Snakeviz is only showing one overall function "built-in method builtins.exec". Anyone know what could be causing this? The function I am profiling calls many sub-functions. Snakeviz sees this, as shown in the table excerpt below the image, it just doesn't show up in the visualisation.

[image: snakeviz example]

Answer (score 5):

cProfile.run does not seem to add callers data to the file.

Instead of using `cProfile.run('main()', "stats.prof")` try this:

```
pr = cProfile.Profile()
pr.enable()
main()
pr.disable()
pr.dump_stats("stats.prof")
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider directly running `cProfile` from command line:

```
python -m cProfile -o output_file script_to_run.py
```

This will allow cProfile to understand your script's running time better.